# How to use WSO2 EI to integrate services and provide the REST API for a web app built using MERN stack?

Tags: node.js, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mern, ei, wso2-esb

I have developed a web application using the **MERN stack**. I want to use **WSO2 EI** in eclipse to create a REST API for my app. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are not quite clear for me. But let me answer with what I have understood.

If you want to use WSO2 EI to integrate services, you can do so with the help of the [WSO2 EI documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Introduction). You can create a [REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Creating+an+API) in the WSO2 EI itself and you can expose it outside. You just have to call the REST API in your webapp to initiate the mediation.

If you have any specific requirements, please clearly mention it in your question.